# Dotnet list-sdks does not list the installed SDKs

Tags: macos, .net-5

I am on Mac and the new .NET 5.0 just got released. I have installed it with dotnet-install.sh

```
dotnet-install.sh --version 5.0.100

dotnet-install: Note that the intended use of this script is for Continuous Integration (CI) scenarios, where:
dotnet-install: - The SDK needs to be installed without user interaction and without admin rights.
dotnet-install: - The SDK installation doesn't need to persist across multiple CI runs.
dotnet-install: To set up a development environment or to run apps, use installers rather than this script. Visit https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download to get the installer.

dotnet-install: .NET Core SDK version 5.0.100 is already installed.
dotnet-install: Adding to current process PATH: `/Users/l1x/.dotnet`. Note: This change will be visible only when sourcing script.
dotnet-install: Note that the script does not resolve dependencies during installation.
dotnet-install: To check the list of dependencies, go to https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/install, select your operating system and check the "Dependencies" section.
dotnet-install: Installation finished successfully.
```

However I cannot see the installed SDK.

```
dotnet --list-sdks
2.2.402 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
3.1.101 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
```

What is the recommended way of installing .NET SDKs from the command line on Mac?

Comment: Do you face any problems following the official documentation? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/core/install/macos#install-with-an-installer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Installing the SDK with Brew solves this problem:

```
brew install --cask dotnet-sdk 

==> Downloading https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/3bdcd7d2-1444-4f7d-a254-504a994ffe39/e4f42b83604673f971748c722aa20bec/dotnet-sdk-5.0.100-osx-x64.pkg
Already downloaded: /Users/l1x/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/29dc1169ad824e06e4077148811a2555d7aa0f27737f8c0ea8e5858044e67a8a--dotnet-sdk-5.0.100-osx-x64.pkg
==> Verifying SHA-256 checksum for Cask 'dotnet-sdk'.
==> Installing Cask dotnet-sdk
==> Running installer for dotnet-sdk; your password may be necessary.
==> Package installers may write to any location; options such as --appdir are ignored.
Password:
installer: Package name is Microsoft .NET SDK 5.0.100 (x64)
installer: Upgrading at base path /
installer: The upgrade was successful.
==> Purging files for version 5.0.100,3bdcd7d2-1444-4f7d-a254-504a994ffe39:e4f42b83604673f971748c722aa20bec of Cask dotnet-sdk
Error: It seems there is already a Binary at '/usr/local/bin/dotnet'.
```

The new SDK appears:

```
dotnet --list-sdks
2.2.402 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
3.1.101 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
5.0.100 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
```

Comment: brew install --cask dotnet-sdk

Comment: i get `Error: Cask 'dotnet-sdk' conflicts with 'dotnet'.`